# How do I filter query objects by time range in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I've got a field in one model like:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

this is what it's looks like if saved:

```
2022-12-13 13:00:29.84166+08
2022-12-13 14:00:29.84166+08
2022-12-13 15:00:29.84166+08
```

Is it possible to filter that by range of time? maybe similar to this?

```
Sample.objects.filter(created_at __range=["13:00", "15:00"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [time](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#time) lookup and then your range to filter by a time range

```
Sample.objects.filter(created_at__time__range=["13:00", "15:00"])
```

Comment: question: this will give all records in different date created between this time interval ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 Yes, it will give results from all dates

Comment: I tried it. Rawdata.objects.filter(created_at__time__range=["13:00", "15:00"]) it's not working for me.